# Reading from a file and parsing required data

Tags: python

I want to read a file and parse the file with required data.

content of the file is given below.

```
ENV: UAT
OS_Template: Windows_2012R2,SOE_W2012R2_64_SE_2020Q2:REDHAT7,SOE_REDHAT_7_2019Q2:Windows_2016,SOE_W2016_64_SE_2020Q2
```

here i would like to parse it as follows

```
blue_print = ['Windows_2012R2', 'REDHAT7', 'Windows_2016']
image = ['SOE_W2012R2_64_SE_2020Q2', 'SOE_REDHAT_7_2019Q2','SOE_W2016_64_SE_2020Q2']
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve this? Asking for the solution and asking for help are two different things

Comment: Assuming the second line is `image:blue_print`, then you cannot have `Windows_2012R2` as a `blue_print` item while `SOE_W2016_64_SE_2020Q2` is an `image` item, if you split on colon

Comment: Atleast try to google something relatable and do some thing before asking. We would love to help if you show some intent.

Comment: my apologies, i have tried reading the file line by line and splitting the line first with :. i didnt paste my code bcz it was bad.

Comment: ```os_tempalte = []
blueprint = []
with open("blueprint_image.txt" , "r") as f1:
  content_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f1]
  env_list = content_list.pop(0)
  content_list = str(content_list)
  new_content =  content_list.split(":")
  new_content.pop(0)
  for i in new_content:
   new_list = i.split(",")
   blueprint = blueprint.append(new_list[0]) 
   os_template= blueprint.append(new_list[0])
```

i am getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Answer (score 0):

I got my desired answer. Following is the code.

```
with open("blueprint_image.txt" , "r") as f1:
  content_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f1]
#Removing Environment
  content_list.pop(0)
  updated_content_list = "".join(content_list)
  print updated_content_list
#converting to string
  new_content =  updated_content_list.split(":")
#Removing OS template
  new_content.pop(0)
  print new_content
  for i in new_content:
   new_list = i.split(",")
   print new_list
   blueprint.append(new_list[0])
   os_template.append(new_list[1])
  for items  in blueprint:
   new_item = items.strip()
   blueprint_updated.append(new_item)
  for items1  in os_template:
   new_item1 = items1.strip()
   os_template_updated.append(new_item1)
print blueprint_updated
print os_template_updated
```